# How to get actual content when JSON.stringify shows empty object but in actual fact, it isn't empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to log my errors and send notification to a channel. When I use console.log() I get a description of the error message but when I use JSON.strigify it returns an empty object. How can I fix this issue please.

When I run this code:

```js
console.log(err);
console.log("stringify", JSON.stringify(err));
```

I get this response:

```js
ReferenceError: School is not defined
    at /Users/macbookpro/Documents...
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/macbookpro/Documents...
    at next (/Users/macbookpro/Documents...
    at adminAccess (/Users/macbookpro/Documents...
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
strinfify {}
```

I need the error message, and for me to send it successfully using axios, I need to JSON.stringify() the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most properties on an error object are [non-enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties), so you need to do something like this:

```js
let error = new Error('nested error message');

console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, 
      error,
      {      // Explicitly pull Error's non-enumerable properties
        name: error.name, 
        message: error.message, 
        stack: error.stack
      }
    )))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest option is to add additional parameter to `JSON.stringify`

```
JSON.stringify(error, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error))
```

Error object properties are not enumerable, thus without specifying them explicitly you're not able to get them. But if you fetch property names as a second parameter of `JSON.stringify` you're able to retrieve them.